# Force Jenkins Subversion plugin to use HEAD revision

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I was using Hudson for doing my project builds and now planning to migrate to Jenkins.

The build server time is not in sync with the developer machines, and hence svn update does not work correctly. In Hudson, I was able to set the revision policy to HEAD, whereas its missing in Jenkins.

I searched a bit and saw that a Jira is created for this issue, but did not find a working solution for the problem.

I tried to manually install the Hudson subversion plugin in Jenkins, and the Revision policy option came up, but for some reason it caused an exception while setting the svn authentication info.

If anyone knows a solution to make this change in Jenkins, kindly reply.

Comment: How much have the clocks drifted? Is NTP to sync the clocks not an option?

Comment: Build server is in GMT and developer machines are in EST. It would be great if a solution is available other than syncing the time, since almost every time we build from head.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out. Append all SVN urls with @HEAD and svn update will happen from HEAD!

Answer (score 1):

The plugin doesn't offer such feature but you might find useful this jira issue. There is a patch in the comments for that purpose. See [Issue 1241](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1241).